# logoSvg.php error site

Tags: php, svg

i put svg file with php extension to add it on the site with php architecture then i embeded it on top.inc.php like so

```
<object data="logoSvg.php" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

I see the logo in the header and i can style it but the hole page content has disapeared. 
My logoSvg.php starts directly with the svg tag.
I put already try to put

```
   <?php
    header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
    ?>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/
    REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
```

before the svg content. But error: xml declaration allowed on the top of document. im lost, which part and where? Tks

Comment: I removed the ?xml? tag. It finally renders the logoSvg in the DOM but i have a blank page now. As soon as i put

Comment: sorry i ways saying as soon as i put <object data="logoSvg.php" type="image/svg+xml" />, the page becomes blank